# Setting up Persistent Data for Carto/Postgresql on ACI

Tags: postgresql, docker, azure-container-service, cartodb, azure-container-instances

**My main objective is to get an image up and running quickly and easily while persisting data. I THINK an ACI is the best way to do this. Assuming this is true...**

[Edit2] It appears that there may be a more fundamental problem is the inability to specify a hostname like you can in docker. I will ask that question in a separate thread. I was able to attach storage.

[Original post]
I would like to use an ACI to setup this an image that is on Docker Hub. I have been able to follow the simple tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal) but I need to attach storage.

Specifically, this is the image that I am using: https://hub.docker.com/r/sverhoeven/cartodb/

These are are instructions for how to setup persistent data but I don't think they will translate directly to an ACI. This is taken from the "Persistent Data" section of that docker hub page

> To persist the PostgreSQL data, the PostGreSQL data dir (/var/lib/postgresql) must be persisted outside the Cartodb Docker container.…

Make a temporary container

```
docker create --name cartodb_pgdata sverhoeven/cartodb
```

Save the Postgresql data dir (cartodb_pgdata) to local directory.
** how do we do this with ACI?

```
docker cp cartodb_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql $PWD/cartodb_pgdata docker rm -f cartodb_pgdata
```

Setup ownership of cartodb_pgdata to the (uid=105) user on file system. ** How do we do this with ACI?

```
sudo chown -R 105.105 $PWD/cartodb_pgdata
```

After this the CartoDB container will have a database that stays filled after restarts. The CartoDB container can be started with

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -h cartodb.example.com -v $PWD/cartodb_pgdata:/var/lib/PostgreSQL sverhoeven/cartodb
```

**There are a number of questions for which I am having trouble finding solutions, eg:**

- I don't know whether to use emptyDir or an Azure file share.
- I don't know how to edit ownership
- I don't know how to setup the ACI to invoke specific docker run commands when spinning up a container

Comment: I haven't gotten any suggestions for a little bit. At the risk of looking like I am asking the same thing twice, I will upload a more precise question about the issue with hostname specification. Generally speaking, the answer from @anders did help me get started with attaching a file share.

Comment: I asked my hostname question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959411/is-there-a-way-to-specify-hostname-when-starting-container-on-azure-cloud-instan

Answer (score 1):

You should use Azure file share as emptyDir is not a persistent storage. Essentially what you need is add a file share volume in your container group and mount it at /var/lib/PostgreSQL. The file share volume will be mounted with 777 permission by default.

Since you already passed the volume info when you create container, e.g. `az container create` via CLI, that translate to underlying `docker run` equivalent. there is no need to specify docker command.

How to mount a file share:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Comment: I see. I will have to look into the CLI. I didn't touch that yet. I just used the standard step-by-step workflow to setup the instance. I'll look into this in the next couple of days and will post back here.

Comment: I can't start the container with the fileshare mounted. I am getting errors on startup.

`* Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server`
    * Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main is not accessible or does not exist
    ...fail!

….
cartodb/config/environments/development.js"
Windshaft tileserver 6.1.1 started on 0.0.0.0:8181 PID=86 (development)
rake aborted!
PG::Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
`
etc etc etc

Comment: I think that this section 
`/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`
is because of me mounting the filesystem

Comment: Sure enough, when I start the container without mounting the file share to that directory, it boots:

`* Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   ...done.
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
 * Starting nginx nginx
   ...done.
--- Restoring user metadata

etc

Comment: The site is not fully loading. I think there is still a problem with not specifying the hostname.  
```Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:53:59 +0000
Processing by Admin::PagesController#index as */*
...
Redirected to http://localhost/login
...
Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:25 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):

Started POST "/sessions/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:39 +0000
Started GET "/user/dev/dashboard/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:39 +0000
```

Comment: Just noting that my issues had to do with permissions issues. I will mark the best answer but warn folks that there is currently a problem for me with file ownership. This may be the case for others too