# Is there a way to specify hostname when starting container on azure cloud instance

Tags: azure, docker, hostname, azure-container-instances

I have been trying to setup a docker image on Azure and am running into an issue.
The image has been designed to require a -h hostname argument when starting it using the docker commands.

The image is here: https://hub.docker.com/r/sverhoeven/cartodb/

I can't translate these commands into something I can do on Azure.

The options for -h are as follows:

> **How to use a different hostname:**
>
> For example to use cartodb.example.com as a hostname start with:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -h cartodb.example.com sverhoeven/cartodb
```

> The chosen hostname should also resolve to an IP adress of the machine where the web server is running.
>   If you don't have a domain/subdomain pointing to your server yet, you can use the servers external ip address:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -h <servers-external-ip-address> sverhoeven/cartodb
```

Here is what happens by not telling the image what hostname to use - Note, when you don't specify the hostname, it defaults to localhost. I am seeing a lot of 127.0.0.1 in the log output and some references to localhost. That is concerning.:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:53:59 +0000
Processing by Admin::PagesController#index as */*
...
Redirected to http://localhost/login
...
Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:25 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
...
Started POST "/sessions/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:39 +0000
Started GET "/user/dev/dashboard/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-20 01:54:39 +0000
```

I am looking for suggestions or solutions.

*Note: This is tangentially related to another question I asked concerning the carto image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915321/setting-up-persistent-data-for-carto-postgresql-on-aci).*

Answer (score 1):

After going around and around, the short answer is no, this is not possible right now. Workaround is to use an environment variable